# I want to start new line after .(dot) symbol.

Tags: apex, string, richtextarea

I'm copying data from RichText Area field to Text Area field,When I copied in Text area field,The data is displaying with HTML tags. So used below code to convert,

```
String.replaceAll('\\<.*?\\>', '');
```

It is working fine,but now I want to start new line after .(dot) symbol.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the newline `\n` character to insert a new line in a text area field.

Something like the following should work:

```
String.replace('.', '.\n');
```